# mlogit in R - coefficients and unknown random parameter

Tags: r, coefficients, mlogit

I'm trying to run mlogit on my data.
My data is:

```
> head(df[c(1:3, 33:45)])
      ID Gender Age Option equipment.A equipment.B equipment.C clean.A clean.B clean.C people.A people.B people.C price.A price.B
1 108630      M  56      A        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
2 115547      F  34      B        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
3 118359      F  51      C        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
4 126656      F  40      C        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
5 127439      F  26      C        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
6 130846      M  69      C        3        3        1      1      3      3         2         3         2     4     3
  price.C
1     4
2     4
3     4
4     4
5     4
6     4
```

My code is:

```
Result <- mlogit.data(mydata, shape = "wide", choice = "Option", varying = 34:45)
Result.mxl <- mlogit(Option ~ equipment + clean + people + price | 0, Result)
summary(Result.mxl)
```

Then, my output is:

```
Frequencies of alternatives:
     A      B      C 
0.3745 0.3525 0.2730 

nr method
4 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 3.12E-07 
gradient close to zero 

Coefficients :
         Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
equipment2  0.467333   0.100203  4.6639 3.103e-06 ***
equipment3  0.431747   0.089822  4.8067 1.535e-06 ***
clean2    1.278133   0.094188 13.5701 < 2.2e-16 ***
clean3    1.603504   0.118145 13.5724 < 2.2e-16 ***
people2 0.438747   0.094280  4.6537 3.261e-06 ***
people3 0.292673   0.115142  2.5419   0.01103 *  
price2     0.641272   0.111956  5.7279 1.017e-08 ***
price3     0.786393   0.100451  7.8286 4.885e-15 ***
price4     1.045555   0.151903  6.8830 5.859e-12 ***
price5     1.965825   0.211786  9.2821 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -2009.3
```

So the problem is that I want to get a table with just one observation of 'equipment', 'clean', 'people' and 'price', as well as table of random coefficients.
(something like this example: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/e3mxlogit.html)

I tried to add another parameters to my code and run:

```
Result.mxl <- mlogit(Option ~ equipment + clean + people + price | 0, Result, 
                   rpar = c(equipment = 'n', clean = 'n', people = 'n', price = 'n'), 
                   panel = TRUE, id.var = "id", alt.levels = c("A","B", "C"))
```

but now I get an error:

```
Error in mlogit.start(formula = formula, data = data, mf = mf, start = start,  : 
  unknown random parameter
```

I would appreciate very much your help!

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this issue? I am running into what appears to be the same problem, as has another user in the post linked to below. Please post if you have found a resolution, if not I will contact the author of mlogit to see if there is possibly a bug in the most recent version. Other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193890/mlogit-unkown-random-parameter-factor-variable

Answer (score 1):

If you use factor variables, mlogit apparently first makes new variables for each factor level with new names. It then works with these names and therefore states 'unknown random variable' if you use the original names. You can figure out what the factor names are by running a normal multinomial logit. Then use coef(summary()) to see what the names of the new variables (one per factor level are) and use these to tell mlogit which variables it should use random coefficients for.